# How to desaturate the background of an image in Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, imagemagick

I need to desaturate the background of this kind of images.

I thought I can find the largest contour and desaturate everything around.

So far I can find the largest contour(not perfect). How I can desaturate the background around it ?

**UPDATE** (2022)

I'm editing my question since I didn't got an answer that helped me.
Maybe now it will be more clear.

So below you can see the original image and the mask. As you can see in the original image the background around the person has a tint of blue/magenta in it. Using the mask i have, I would like to desaturate that blue/magenta tint. How I can do that ? I know I need to inverse that mask...but from there...I'm lost...

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('picture.jpg')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgray = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgray, (9, 9), 0)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -5, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', image)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You want to desaturate and remove all the colour from the white background? What effect are you hoping that will create?

Comment: Do you want to remove the background from the image? (make the background transparent?)

Comment: What do you want for the background?  White or pure gray or transparent or black? Gray shades have no saturation -  they are already desaturated.

Comment: @MarkSetchell there's a lot of blue/magenta sometime even some yellow/green in that "white" background so yeah - i just need to desaturate those...

Comment: @0dminnimda no no, i just need to desaturate all the colours from that so called "white" background.

Comment: @fmw42 Pure gray would be ideal.

Comment: any ideas anyone ?

Comment: @fmw42 need your help here

Comment: @ Andie31 Unless you have a mask of the woman including the white jacket and white shoes, I do not know how to do that. Anything done to the picture as a whole would modify the white jacket and white shoes.

Comment: I do have a mask...all I need is desaturate the blue mostly....

Comment: @fmw42 I updated my question, can you please have a look now ? I added the mask. Thank you